# What is causing the hash (#) in url to disappear?

Tags: jquery, html

On a page with a url like `mypage.php#tab3` having a link that looks like:

[image]

Clicking on Add results in the url shortening to `mypage.php#`

Code of the Add:

```
function addComment(i) {
    var s = document.getElementById(i);

    s.innerHTML = '';
    $('#'+i).attr('style','width:164px;padding-right:5px');
    $('#'+i).append('<input type="text" id="ci'+i.substr(3)+'" style="width:162px;padding:0 3px" value=\'Enter comment here\' onclick=\"\" onblur="storeComment('+i.substr(3)+');">');
    return false;
}
```

I added somes breaks and the hash disappears **after** the return false statement.

Unsuccessful changes tried:

1. With and without onclick
2. With and without return false

EDIT: The problem is in the link code.

```
<a href="#" onclick="addComment('com94');">Add</a>
```

Comment: What's the HTML for your links look like?

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="....  Looking at the problem as you were. Thanks.

Comment: Can't quite understand your last comment. Is your problem solved? :-)

Comment: You will have to show us the code for your event handler.  You probably need to do `preventDefault()` to stop the default handling of the link.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville The problem is solved and was in the href. The `href="#'` was being executed. It can be solved (temporarily) with `href="#tab3"`. As a result, I'm now looking at making this a button.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you for replying. I really need to look at `<button>` since this is not in a form.

Comment: Why is this tagged as a jQuery question? There is no jQuery...

Comment: @GísliKonráð  My level of knowledge of jQuery does not allow for ignoring the possible effects of using it. The first code snip does contain 2 lines of jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to return `false` in the onclick handler to prevent link's default action (going to the `href`) from being executed.

```
<a href="#" onclick="addComment('com94');return false;">Add</a>
```

Or, as your `addComment()` function already returns `false`, just delegate it through.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return addComment('com94');">Add</a>
```

This is by the way not a jQuery problem, it's just basic HTML.

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you for including a lesson.